# Can Radio Buttons be used in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I read the Xamarin docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/radiobutton and tried to follow the **exact** syntax given in the doc to include a radiobutton in my project. The code is as follows :

```
<StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
        
       <widget:RadioButton Text="Cat" />
    
   </StackLayout>
```

The error I get here is **'invalid type: expected type is 'View', actual type is 'RadioButton'** Is there a way to solve this ?

Comment: did you follow the instructions, including the "Important" note in the blue box?  And why are you using a "widget" prefix?

Answer (score 3):

I think what your looking for in Xamarin.Forms is the control <RadioButton../> without the widgetpart.This will create a radiobutton in the native controls for UWP, iOS and Android.

This is the code I use to display radiobuttons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestButton.MainPage">

    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <RadioButton Text="test radio button"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Beware it is experimental and you will need to add the build flag for it.
[build flag for experimental XamarinForms controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/internals/experimental-flags)

If you want to add the experimental flag for the RadioButton, you have to do so in all your projects (iOS, Android and UWP).I've added images to clarify where exactly (they need to be before the Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init). This is the code to add:

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags(new string[] { "RadioButton_Experimental" });
```

Here's where to add the code in the Android project. MainActivity.cs
[image: experimental flag radiobutton for android]

Here's where to add the code in the iOS project. AppDelegate.cs
[image: experimental flag radiobutton for ios]

Here's where to add the code in the UWP project. App.xaml.cs
[image: experimental flag radiobutton for uwp]